# unable to push multiple embeds after mongoid upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I recently updated mongoid to 6.x.  In one of my rspec tests I was persisting embedded docs using this convention:

```
parent.children.push(child1, child2, child3, etc...)
```

In this case both the parent and child models have after_update callbacks.  This was working fine, but after the mongoid upgrade I now get:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `call' for #<ActiveSupport::Callbacks::CallbackSequence:0x00007fcde9684c00>)
```

If I change the test to do individual pushes, it works fine, i.e.:

```
parent.children.push(child1)
parent.children.push(child2)
etc...
```

I've searched around quite a bit but have yet to turn up anything related to this.  Am I just "doing it wrong"?

Comment: try `parent.push(childrens: [child1, child2, child3])`

Answer (score 0):

I tried `parent.push(childrens: [...])` as suggested, which yielded this error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `bson_type' for #<Child:0x00007fd7073ce520>
from /mongoid-6.1.1/lib/mongoid/attributes/dynamic.rb:137:in `method_missing'
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this may have been an issue with the version of Mongoid.  I didn't realize it was up to v.7 now.  I updated to latest 7.0.2 and this issue seems to be resolved.

Comment: did you face any other issues after upgrade to v7.0.2? I plan to upgrade my project as well.